# What is the meaning of subsampling level in machine learning/statistics?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, sampling, learning, descriptive-statistics

I am reading a paper but nowhere it is defined but the term is being used a lot.

The paper is - Less is More : Nystrom Computational Regularization -Rudi,Camariano, 
               Rosasco
 Link :          https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5936-less-is-more-nystrom-computational-regularization.pdf

Comment: It would probably help if you mentioned what article you are reading and better if you could provide a link.

Comment: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5936-less-is-more-nystrom-computational-regularization.pdf